# in xtragrid double click on a cell and that value should display in lookupedit

Tags: c#, devexpress

I created one XtraGrid and added some values with the help of LookUpEdit and some TextBoxes. 
I want to modify the values what I have added into grid here.
I am using `getfocusedrowcellvalue` to get values from grid into TextBoxes.
How can I get that `getfocusedrowcellvalue` to LookUpEdit?

example:-
txtdrmk.Text = Convert.ToString(gridView3.GetFocusedRowCellValue("remark"));//to get value from selected cell to text box.

cmbper     // this is my lookupedit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Hi there you should check out "How To Ask" section.

Comment: Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . try to improve the question format

Comment: ok I Edited Question

Answer (score 0):

If you fire a `FocusedRowChanged` event, you can certainly do what you seek by using the `GetFocusedRow()` method against the grid view:

```
object o = grdCommentsView.GetFocusedRow();
```

From here, if your data source is a domain object, you can just cast it to that object type:

```
Customer c = o as Customer;
```

Or, if the datasource is a datatable:

```
DataRow dr = o as DataRow;
```

All that said, there is a much better way, in my opinion.  Use a binding source component, bind your data (object collection or DataTable) to the binding source `DataSource` property, then make the binding source the data source for both the grid and any non-grid controls you have.  You can access these via the `(DataBindings)` property.

The best part about this approach is that the data binding is codeless*, and as you change rows on the grid the values in the controls will automatically update.  If you change the property value either place (control or grid), the other will reflect the update.

If you use the DataLayoutControl, it will even do the data binding for you.

Comment: with the help of store procedure I binded the xtragrid and I used datalayoutcontrol to create texboxes(text edit) and lookup edit